# unknown filter ":markdown-it" when compile pug

Tags: pug

I ran into this error when trying to compile pug with `pug -w ./examples/resume -o ./dist/resume -P`

The error says

`unknown filter ":markdown-it"`

After searching for solution, I have installed the packages by running `npm i jstransformer-marked -S` and `npm install markdown-it` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) and [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) are both Markdown parsers. Which one do you want to use?

If you want to use Marked:

1. Install [`jstransformer-marked`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstransformer-marked).
2. Use the `:marked` filter in Pug.

If you want to use markdown-it:

1. Install [`jstransformer-markdown-it`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstransformer-markdown-it).
2. Use the `:markdown-it` filter in Pug.

There might not be need to install `marked` or `markdown-it`.